# Code that would show the countries with a greater GDP than any country

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and was trying to solve a question on SQLzoo

> Select the code that would show the countries with a greater GDP than any country in Africa (some countries may have NULL gdp values).

My answer to the question was

```
    SELECT name FROM bbc
    WHERE gdp > ALL (SELECT gdp 
                     FROM bbc 
                     WHERE region = 'Africa' 
                     AND gdp<>NULL)
```

But the correct answer on the site is

```
SELECT name FROM bbc
 WHERE gdp > (SELECT MAX(gdp) 
              FROM bbc 
              WHERE region = 'Africa')
```

I am not getting why the answer selected by me is wrong

[Quiz Question No 5](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Nested_SELECT_Quiz)

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use.

Comment: I don't think your answer is wrong. Comparing with the `MAX()` aggregate might be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @Shadow I using the one which is used by sqlzoo. [Engines](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SQLZOO:About)

Comment: @Corion But when I run the Query they both gives different results.I am not getting the reason behind that

Comment: @sql_learner it is your task to select the correct one. But do not select conflicting ones.

Comment: @Shadow Yeah sure.Will take care from now onwards :)

Comment: Ah - the "ALL" operator ( https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_any_all.asp ) returns true if ALL of the rows meet the citeria, and doesn't return the value itself. That might be it. Thanks for teaching me about this operator!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `> all (...)` solution selected by you is the fact that some of the gdp values is null.

When you compare a non-null value with a null, then the result is null, unless you use a null-safe operator, such as `is null`.

Comment: I thought that `gdp<>NULL`  takes care of that part

Comment: Is there any difference between `gdp is not null` and `gdp<>NULL`

Comment: @sql_learner Instead of `<>`, you can use null-safe operator `<=>` . eg: `gdp <=> null` Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for the letting me know the alternative way of using MIN/MAX

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yeah sure I will try with that as well

Comment: My first comment was wrong. Comparing `gdp<>NULL` returns UNKNOWN for every row, thus no row is returned by the Subquery and the `> ALL` comparison returns every row in your table. But the `MAX` subquery will return no row if it returns NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same question wrong.
Got this from somewhere

> Because the NULL value cannot be equal or unequal to any value, you cannot perform any comparison on this value by using operators such as '=' or '<>'.

On testing, `50 <> null` doesn't give the usual boolean `0` but gives `null`